# Backbone beginner can't make view appear on screen

Tags: backbone.js

Can anyone help me to figure out why anything happens when I load this html? It's being served locally with Python's SimpleHTTPServer and for now all I want is to make the words sample and user appear on the screen.

**main.js**

```
    /* Model */

    var User = Backbone.Model.extend({});

    var sample_user = new User({
        name: {
          first: 'sample',
          last: 'user'
        }
    });

    /* View */

    var UserView = Backbone.View.extend({

        tagName: 'div',

        className: 'card',

        template: _.template( $('#card_template').html() ),

        render: function() {
          this.$el.html( this.template( this.model.toJSON() ) );
          return this;
        }

    });

    var sample_card = new UserView({ model: sample_user });
    sample_card.render();
```

**main.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Backbone kickstart</title>
</head>
<body>
  <script type="text/template" id="card_template">
    <h1><%= name.first + ' ' + name.last %></h1>
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.5.2/underscore.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.1.0/backbone.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.1/d3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/topojson/1.1.0/topojson.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Backbone's `render`, by default, doesn't do anything to the page when you're building your own `el`. Your `render`:

```
render: function() {
  this.$el.html( this.template( this.model.toJSON() ) );
  return this;
}
```

simply fills in the view's `el` but no one actually adds the `el` to the page. The usual pattern in your case would be something like this:

```
var sample_card = new UserView({ model: sample_user });
$('body').append(sample_card.render().el);
```

While I'm here, I recommend against putting your templates inside `<body>`, that makes it very easy to accidentally overwrite them. You'll have a better time if they're in `<head>` which you probably won't be manipulating.

Comment: Great answer, thanks for your help. By the way, is it possible to place templates on external .html files?

Comment: It is possible but leaves you with unpleasant AJAX issues. Usually you'd set up the server code to grab the appropriate template files and inline them in `<head>` for you. Adding a bit of node.js code server-side to precompile your templates into a `JST = { 'template-name' : compiled_template_function, ... }` structure is also quite common, then the compiled templates would be in a `.js` file that you could include like any other `.js` file. Remember that `f = _.template(x)` returns a function and that function's JavaScript source is in `f.source`.

Comment: Ohh ok then. I think for now I'll just stick with your suggestions and wait to see what's coming next as Eric Bidelman presents in his tutorial. [HTML's New Template Tag, standardizing client-side templating](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/template/).
 I strongly expect a simpler and more modularised future for all web technologies. JS is already on this path.